# Linux - Can't recursively delete large directories

Tags: linux, bash

I have a pretty big `find` that is supposed to delete any files/dir it finds. I just can't get it to work properly.

If I attach `-exec rm -fr {} \;`, at some point, I always get the following errors:

```
find: ‘/path/to/dir/file123.local’: No such file or directory
```

If I replace it with `-delete`, I get the following error:

```
find: cannot delete `/path/to/dir': Directory not empty
```

I looked for suggestions online but the suggestion is always the other option (replace `-exec` with `-delete` and vice-versa)

Does anyone happen to know a way to fix it without redirecting stderr to null?

Thanks ahead!

Comment: Why do you need `find`, if you want to delete **everything**? Just do a `rm -rf` on the top level directory.

Comment: The find has lots of parameters for things like days old etc

Comment: Sure, but you wrote _to delete **any** files/dir it finds_, and once you are using a `-exec rm -fr`, everything below is removed, no matter what restriction you impose. For instance, if the topmost directory already happens to fulfil your restriction, you will delete everything below - not because finds it, but because your `rm` gets rid of it.

Comment: any dir that it **finds with those parameters**. I have to use find, because it's all about deleting dirs that match the find params.

Comment: In this case, it is probably easier to write two `find`s, where the first one matches the directories you want to delete, and the second the files. You can try to combine them with `-o` and `-prune`, but it may be more trouble than it is worth to get it working.

Comment: Another approach is to use your `find` and emit the matches into a file. Then process the file in a way that you can feed it into `xargs rm -rf` without getting errors.

Comment: You should use `-prune` to prevent `find` from trying to descend into directories that you have deleted with `rm -rf`.

Answer (score 1):

`find` doesn't know what your command passed to `-exec` does. It traverses the directory tree in this order:

1. find a file
2. execute a command on that file
3. if it's a directory, traverse it down

Now if the directory is removed with `rm -fr`, there is nothing to traverse down any more, so `find` reports it.

If you supply the `-depth` option, then the traversal order changes:

1. find a file
2. if it's a directory, traverse it down
3. execute a command on that file

This will eliminate the error message.

`-delete` implies `-depth`, so ostensibly it should work. However it is your responsibility to make sure the directories you want to delete are *completely* cleaned up. If you filter out some files with `-time` etc, you may end up trying to delete a directory which is not completely clean.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to wrap `{}` in double quotes, there may have space in directry path.

```
-exec rm -rf "{}" \;
```

Comment: This does not change anything because quotes only affect shell expansions. `{}` and `"{}"` both result in the same curly braces being passed to `find`

Answer (score 0):

If I read your question well, you want to remove files, but sometimes it happens that they already have been removed by some other process, and you wonder what you should do.
Why do you think you should do anything? You want the file to be gone, and apparently it is gone, so no worries.

Obviously the corresponding error messages might be annoying, but this you can handle adding `2>/dev/null` at the end of your command (redirect the error output to `<NULL>`).

So you get:

```
find ... -exec rm -fr {} \; 2>/dev/null
```

**Edit** after comment from [user1934428](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1934428/user1934428):

I might be a good idea to drop the `r` switch:

```
find ... -exec rm -f {} \; 2>/dev/null
```

In that case, you should have no errors anymore:

```
find ... -exec rm -f {} \;
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, it's because all the finds are centrilized in a python file, executed by a CI platform, and since this returns a 1 return code, it stops.

Comment: ... and when you add `2>/dev/null`, does it still return 1?

Comment: Of course it won't, but I'm worried of missing possible important errors in the future.

Comment: @Dominique : They are not removed _by some other process_: `find` builds a list of files/directories to proceed, then walks over this list and executes a `rm -rf` on them. Due to the `-r` options, entries below (which still are on _find_'s todo-list) get deleted, and when find then wants to run the -exec on them, they are gone. `find` and `rm -r` simply don't work along.

Comment: @rogersjoshmac: as proposed by the other guy (such a difficult name :-) ), it might be a good idea to drop the `r` switch.

Comment: Thanks for the response, so if I drop the `-r`, the subdirs of the directory would still be removed?

Comment: If you drop the `r`, then the files will be removed, not the directories. If you leave the `r`, the files and the directories will be removed but you will face the error messages (Sorry, when I added my last line in my answer, I had forgotten that you needed to remove the directories too). I guess that my first trick, adding the `2>/dev/null`, will be your final solution.